# Python while loop,elif loop pause

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm try to create the time base data send and receiving program for my mini project using firebase database but i have a problem.below code shows the main loop of my project,when i start executing this program will struct(not executing) and another problem **elif** loop will not properly.here i'm using raspberry pi 3B+.so please tell me the solution for this problem.time will me in 24 hour format

```
while True:
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    hour=now.strftime("%H")
    minite=now.strftime("%M")
    second=now.strftime("%S")
    if second==("00"):
        if (minite=="30"or"37"):
            update_firebase()       
    elif (second=="00"):
        if (minite=="56"):
            if (hour=="18"):
              downlod_firebase()
    else:
        print ("Error")
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: The elif is the same as the `if` statement so it'll never get that far, it looks as though you're trying to schedule a task so you'd be better off using either celery or cron

Comment: Side note: none of the parentheses in the `if` and `elif` parts are needed.

Comment: RE: `if (minite=="30"or"37"):` see [How to test multiple variables against a value?](//stackoverflow.com/q/15112125).

Comment: how can i adopt the cron in this program?@Sayse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Your `if` and `elif` have the same condition
- You are not comparing against multiple values correctly
- Extra parens are not needed
- Why convert to string when you are dealing with ints?

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
if now.second == 0 and (now.minute == 30 or now.minute == 37):
    update_firebase()
elif now.second == 0 and now.minute == 56 and now.hour == 18:
    downlod_firebase()
else:
    print ("Error")
    time.sleep(1)
```